# Computed column for simple multiplication?

Tags: database, database-design

I making a simple inventory application. In a table i have columns Quantity, Price and TotalPrice.
Which is better, make TotalPrice a `Computed Column` as Quantity*Price or do this calculation in my application and save it in TotalPrice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One rule in database design is (in general): do not store information that can also be retrieved easily.

In your case I would not create a computed column, but do the multiplication during retrieval. Either by directly selecting `price * quantity` or by creating a view that contains this computation.

The view has the added benefit, that you can easily change the formula (e.g. including VAT) without the need to change all statements in your application.

Comment: It centralizes the definition of that (admittedly simply) computation. If only used for retrieval (e.g. reports), I would go for the view. However depending on your DBMS and programming language it might create some problems when you try to update the data through the view. If that is the case, I'd add the multiplication to the SELECT statement or simply do it in the application. It depends on your environment. There is no "golden rule" for this.

Comment: A view sounds good. If the "TotalPrice" calculation changes in the future, you only change the view, rather than 500 queries. Or you could call a function in your queries for the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for that rule, for my small size application I must not store it as it can be easily calculated

Comment: What if the calculation is not easily retrieved? And What it is simple calculation but it's being retrieved many times? Such as in exports to CSV or something?

Comment: @RazaFarooq: a "simple calculation" never warrants redundant storage (and especially not something like `price * quantity`). If it's really expensive then using things like persisted computed columns or materialized views can be used - but this depends highly on the DBMS being used.

Answer (score 1):

If you update price or quantity you are forced to make a 2cd update on TotalPrice. What if another developer forgets the 2cd update? Now you have bad data.

You could have a trigger keep it in sync, but the possibility for bad data still exists. In some RDMS's the triggers do not fire for each row updated in a set-based update.

But sometimes it's needed to store calculated fields. If the table is BIG and you plan on searching the calculated field. (you must store the data to index it). In some designs you not only store the calculated fields, but aggregate calculations as well.

It's not always wrong to store calculated fields, just make sure you know the trade offs.

*** EDIT ***
Another point. If you calculate "Amount_Paid", the actual amount the customer paid will be lost when you change the calculation formula.

Design to solve the problem. If that means breaking a rule of thumb, then break some thumbs.
*** END EDIT ***

Comment: I'd only add that it would be wrong to store a column that could be calculated without having a CHECK() constraint on that column to make sure things always added up.

Answer (score 0):

why store a computed column when you can do the computations in the query?

```
SELECT (Quantity * Price) as TotalPrice FROM my_table
```

Comment: And if TotalPrice is changed, and requires say tax. Then you only have to change in one place, not every query