# Priority Database size or Performance c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, performance

Sometimes we find our self in situation where we have to choose one from database size or performance.

I am working on application for bill accounting in which i store details of bill in table design

```
 BillNo ProductName  Qty Rate
 1       aaaa        1   12
```

I learned that its not good to store data we can calculate at run time in database like `Amount(Qty*Rate)` `, Tax(Amount*5/100)`.

But at some point i need Total amount and total vat for thousands of entries, if i follow above approach first i need to select  `Qty , Rate` then perform multiplication for each row then perform addition which will be definitely time consuming.

What i was thinking:-
 Move on with approach which stores data like

```
 BillNo ProductName  Qty Rate  Tax   Amount
 1       aaaa        1   12     4      16
```

**Disadvantage:-**

1. Need to store extra data in database and which will increase some performance overhead also for insertion of Tax and Amount.

**Advantage:-**

1. Need to select only one value from database.
2. No need to perform multiplication operation, which will improve my performance.

Which one is better and efficient in condition like this .

Above question is just an example to explain the condition. Mainly question is about whether i go with computed columns or calculation during retrieval. As Calculation during retrieval is good if you don't have large no of records but it is against database rules. Is choice between computed columns or calculation during retrieval depend upon no of records.

Comment: Why don't you test execution times?

Answer (score 1):

I always feel you need to worry about performance when it becomes a real issue.

I know that this is a simple example, but given the correct indexes a RDBMS like SQL Server will make easy of calculations like these.

I would put the actual design first. Ensure that your design is logical and business correct.

You could always test the theory by populating the tables with various amounts of data (ranging from small to extremely large data sets ie millions of rows) and testing the performance.

Comment: if i execute query like this "select sum(Qty*Rate) from table " for 1st approach will it be better or "select sum(amount) from table" for second approach .

Comment: Again, as I said, you should test this, and if the performance impact is as great as you feel it would be, rather store the value. Other than that, rather calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a view as it has the added benefit of easily changing the formula (e.g. formula for TAX) without the need to change all statements in your application.

see similar need here [Computed column for simple multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708539/computed-column-for-simple-multiplication)