# Column Depending on other column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a mysql table name 'members' where payment and ewallet are two columns... I want to make `ewallet` column such that it will automatically update when payment will update.. the rule will be `ewallet=0.75*payment`. How it is possible?

there is another column 'enroller_id' through which i am calculation the left count and the right count downline with the php function

```
function getTotalLeg($node,$leg){
$sql="select enrolled_id from members where enroller_id='$node' and tside='$leg' and active='1'";

$res=mysql_query($sql);

global $total;

$total=$total+mysql_num_rows($res);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

 if($row['enrolled_id']!=''){
   getTotalLeg ($row['enrolled_id'],0);
   getTotalLeg ($row['enrolled_id'],1);
  }

return $total;
}
```

Is it possible to count it in the database? Please help me in detail way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). In combination with [Stored Procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) you are able to do quite interesting stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`generated columns`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) (MySQL 5.7.6+):

> **Values of a generated column are computed from an expression included in the column definition.**
>
> Generated column definitions have this syntax:
>
> col_name data_type [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression)   [VIRTUAL |
>   STORED] [UNIQUE [KEY]] [COMMENT comment]   [[NOT] NULL] [[PRIMARY]
>   KEY]

```
CREATE TABLE members(
   ...,
   ewallet DECIMAL(14,4) AS (0.75 * payment)
);
```

Comment: Two clarifications: it is not MySQL **5.7+** - it is **5.7.6+**. Source is the link you have provided to MySQL documentation(section "CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns"). Second - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4708560/25429) contains some important points why similar use-case should not  be implemented with `computed/calculated column`.

Comment: @zloster Yes, 5.7.6. Second part as always it depends.

Comment: Because of the "it depends" I've added my remark. We can't be sure if the asker have thought about the implications :)