# concatenate column values by jumping over nulls

Tags: mysql

if `col1` has value `lorem` or `null`
`col2` - `ipsum` or `null`
`col3` - `dolor` or `null`

`col4` should be `lorem,ipsum,dolor` if there is no `null` inside preceding columns.

if, for example, `col2` is `null` the result should be `lorem,dolor`

something like - `update table set col4 = concat(col1, col2, col3)` - but jumping over nulls

Is this possible using mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

> CONCAT_WS() does not skip empty strings. However, **it does skip any NULL values after the separator argument.**

```
update table set col4 = concat_ws(',', col1, col2, col3);
```

---

To avoid running update every time I suggest to use [generated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681048/column-depending-on-other-column/35681114#35681114):

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT, col1 TEXT, col2 TEXt, col3 TEXT,
   col4 TEXT AS (concat_ws(',', col1, col2, col3))
)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d5f3973bc0af0ba10b630ec5ff90c7b)**